# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method getDrawable on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm new to android development hence actual code is appreciated. thanks in advance.

Here's my code. I'm using `Viewpager`.

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        BitmapDrawable btmpdraw = (BitmapDrawable) imgflag.getDrawable();
        Bitmap btmp = btmpdraw.getBitmap();

        File cache = getApplicationContext().getExternalCacheDir();
        File sharefile = new File(cache, "toshare.png");
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(sharefile);
            btmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
```

**Here's my logcat:**

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           Process: kokamapps.viewpagertutorial, PID: 2049
                                                                           **java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.graphics.drawable.Drawable android.widget.ImageView.getDrawable()' on a null object reference**
                                                                               at kokamapps.viewpagertutorial.MainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(MainActivity.java:75)
                                                                               at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2967)
                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:403)
                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatActivity.java:189)
                                                                               at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:100)
                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:663)
                                                                               at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:811)
                                                                               at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
                                                                               at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:958)
                                                                               at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:948)
                                                                               at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:618)
                                                                               at android.support.v7.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:139)
                                                                               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4794)
                                                                               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19905)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:139)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5298)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:950)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:745)

Comment: Means `imgflag ` is `null` make sure initializing `imgflag ` before calling `getDrawable ()` method